# ueye ros driver not working properly

Tags: ros, ueye

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a ueye IDS camera, model 1220LE-C, and I have tried the following ueye driver:

ros.org/wiki/ueye

With this driver, after a number of frames the camera pauses, but continues after 2 or 3 seconds. To check if it was a hardware or software compatibility problem I used the following ROS driver, without experimenting any problems:

ros.org/wiki/ueyecamera

So it seems to be a ROS driver problem with my camera model. Has anyone experimented the same behaviour with the first driver?

PD: running ROS fuerte, on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits and IDS driver version 4.20_64_Bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67172/ueye-ros-driver-not-working-properly/) by [morera3](https://answers.ros.org/users/5398/morera3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen kind of similar issue (with UI155xSE-C) and ended up getting success by replacing mother board (, which was causing many other issues as well anyway). In addition, changing `zoom` size in `cfg` (and build the package) worked for us to get smooth images too. HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by the user, I tested the driver in another board and it worked. It seemed to be related with the graphic card adapter.

The problems appeared using an HP ProBook 4540s, which has a HD Graphics 3000 graphic adapter. In other computers with distinct graphic adapter there are no problems and all works ok.

---

Originally posted by [morera3](https://answers.ros.org/users/5398/morera3/) with karma: 23 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue. Yeah, I think it is the driver not compatible with the camera model.  I used the old "ueyecamera"  driver instead of the "ueye" driver, and now it is working.

---

Originally posted by [z3391384](https://answers.ros.org/users/20056/z3391384/) with karma: 11 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1